# how to get variable from URL without =?

Tags: php

So i have been googling around

I now can do

> index.php?action=something

but how can I make it to

> index.php?something

directly?

Best regards,

Comment: If you are using `.htaccess` then you can define variable name in htaccess rule. and then get in php file `$_GET['variableName']`

Comment: Search for mod_rewrite based on your web server. It will be different between web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution without use htaccess

```
<?php

IF (ISSET($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])){
    $action = substr(strstr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "?"), 1);
    switch ($action) {
        case 'select':
            echo "SELECT";
            break;

        case 'insert':
            echo "INSERT";
            break;

        default:
            echo "nothing";
            break;
    }

}
?>

<p><a href="index.php?select">action: select</a></p>
<p><a href="index.php?insert">action: insert</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess paste this code

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?(.+)$ index.php?action=$1
```

in your php file

```
$term = $_GET['action'];
```

so it will look like this

```
https://example.com/index.php?something
```